# Werden Zahlen gebeugt?

Tags: numbers, adjective-ending

Mir ist es aufgefallen, dass manchmal Zahlen mit Endungen gebeugt werden...

> Es fanden sich Unterschiede zwischen den zweier Herstellern und zwischen dem Messort LWS 
>   oder Femur.

u.

> Außerdem gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen den zweien englischen Sätzen.

Wieso brauchen die Zweien in diesen Sätzen Endungen? Werden andere Zahlen gebeugt (Ich habe das nur mit 2 gesehen)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die Zahlen eins, zwei und drei bilden in der Tat Ausnahmen, was die Deklination betrifft.

Die Zahl *eins* entspricht dem unbestimmten Artikel und wird somit normal dekliniert. Beispiele:

> Ich kaufe einen Besen. (Akkusativ)
>   Das ist die Arbeit einer einzigen Schülerin. (Genitiv)

Die Zahlen *zwei* und *drei* werden, wenn sie nicht in Verbindung mit Präpositionen verwendet werden, **im Genitiv und Dativ** dekliniert. Allerdings wird statt des Genitivs meist die Präposition *von* verwendet:

> Die Produkte von zwei Herstellern

wird in der Alltagssprache vermutlich öfter verwendet werden als

> Die Produkte zweier Hersteller

---

Alle anderen Zahlen verbinden sich mit dem Plural und werden nicht dekliniert:

> Die Hand hat fünf Finger
>   Der Mann gewann 100.000 Euro.

Für Genitiv und Dativ muss immer eine Präposition verwendet werden:

> Die Produkte von fünf Herstellern waren fehlerhaft.

---

Zum zweiten Beispiel oben. Der Satz darf so nicht verwendet werden:

> Außerdem gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen den zweien englischen Sätzen. *(falsch)*

Da ein bestimmter Artikel verwendet wird, muss der Satz so lauten:

> Außerdem gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen den zwei englischen Sätzen.

Comment: Wenn *zwei* nur mit `Dativ` und `Genitiv` dekliniert wird, warum hat *zwei* in "Die Produkte von zwei Herstellern"  keine *-en* Endung? Gibt es ein Beispiel, wo in der Tat `Dativ` zu Beugung führt?

Comment: Nur bei "eins", soweit ich das übersehen:

Die Produkte von *einem* Hersteller, eines Herstellers.
Die Produkte von zwei oder drei Herstellern. Die Produkte zweier oder dreier Hersteller. Die Produkte von vier Herstellern.

Comment: @c.p. Die Zahl eins ist eine besondere Ausnahme, da sie eigentlich der unbestimmte Artikel ist.

Comment: @splattne & Ingmar. Das glaub ich schon, da oben steht aber, dass *zwei* und *drei* auch.

Comment: @c.p., Ingmar Hab das jetzt ergänzt. danke!

Comment: Bei Nominalisierungen von Zahlwörtern oder Substantivgruppen mit Zahlwort, in denen vorher genannte Substantive weggelassen werden, können(!) auch andere Zahlen dekliniert werden: `Welchen (Strauß Blumen) willst du haben? → Von den Vieren will ich keinen, aber von den Zehnen da drüben würde ich einen nehmen.`

Comment: Die Zahlwörter der Zehnerpotenzen können übrigens auch im Nominativ Plurale haben: `Hunderte Menschen sind bei dem Erdbeben gestorben.` `Tausende Menschen haben demonstriert.` `Millionen Menschen leider Hunger.` (Für mich unklar: `Zig Abgeordnete stimmten dagagen.`)

Comment: Wenn wir schon alle Zahlwörter erwähnen, sollten wir *dutzende* (Ein Dutzend = 12 Stück) nicht vergessen. Anders als zB Schock (5 Dutzend) oder Gros (12 Dutzend) wird es in der gesprochenen Sprach weiterhin verwendet.